How to address null reference assignment warning when nullable check is performed and handled
Is there a way to tell the compiler that a following check will ensure that Item is not null and it is safe in the rest of the code and the CS8601 warning is not needed?
The warning, which technically true, does not consider that it's handled in the subsequent line and doesn't need to generate a warning.
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var test = new Test();
test.Init();

public class Test
{
    public record Item(string Name, int Total);

    public Item MyItem { get; set; } = null!;
    public int MyItemTotal { get; set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        MyItem = GetItems().FirstOrDefault();
        if (MyItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MyItemTotal = MyItem.Total;
        }
    }

    private List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>();
    }
}

In the above code MyItem = GetItems().FirstOrDefault(); shows as a warning, which is technically correct. However, the following line does a check and exits. I am looking for a way to tell the compiler "I know and I'm handling it, no need to warn."
The main reason is that I don't want to ignore warnings and I don't want pragmas all over the code.
Is there a clean way to do it?
EDIT
Here's an example on a Razor webpage where if MyItem is null we would redirect away from the page. It is safe to assume in this code that MyItem will never be null. But the warning will always be displayed because Item is not nullable.
public Item MyItem { get; set; } = null!;

public IActionresult OnGet()
{
    MyItem = GetItems().FirstOrDefault();
    if (MyItem == null)
    {
        return Redirect("/");
    }
        
    return Page();
}



It would help if you could provide a [mcve] instead of pseudocode - you appear to use Item as both the name of a type and the name of a variable. (I'd also strongly encourage you to follow normal. NET naming conventions, e.g. starting local variables with lower case letters, even for sample code. Anything that distracts the reader harms the post.)

Here's a working console app that I hope shows the issue and what I am trying to do.

Does this answer your question? What does null! statement mean?

Well that's rather different from before - aside from anything else, what happens if someone doesn't call Init()? Then MyItem will be null, so why would you want to claim it definitely won't be? There are various attributes about handling initialization methods, but your previous example looked like it was about a local variable, so I don't know which you're actually interested in. There are significant differences in the answers I'd give in those questions...

It wasn't meant to be construed as a local variable, it's a property/field. I chopped away too much in the name of brevity. The assumption is that if we got beyond the Init code it's not null (we exited in some way). At some point we have to trust that the code has been validated or we wouldn't have gotten this far, right? Otherwise, we have to assume everything can be null and check is required every time we're going to access it.
If this were a webpage, for example, we would redirect away from it. The page can safely move forward that this property is not ever going to be null.

I added an example of what a Razor OnGet method that redirects away would look like. While not as easily reproducible as the console app, I think it shows why I think we're safe to assume that MyItem will not be null. If someone were to remove the redirect, then they should change MyItem to be nullable to correctly indicate expectations.

@PoulBak I don't believe so. I understand the use of null!. I think my latest edits elucidate more of the actual intent and use. Trying to simplify the code muddied it :( In this case I am telling the compiler that even though there's no initialization code, it won't be null because if it is null we will exit and no further code will be executed.

The value of MyItem can be changed by a different thread between assigning the value and checking the value. If want to signal the compiler the guarantee that it won't be null, don't allow anybody to change it behind your back – use a local variable, those can't be changed

Why not declare MyItem as nullable? Why do MyItem and MyItemTotal have public setters? There's a lot more that seems wrong here than just the nullability warning. Each class is responsible for its own correctness. Correctness should not depend on knowledge of how it's used, e.g. your Razor page.

@KevinKrumwiede we can make the setter private. It was a "prop" in VS to copy this code. The page (class) has a property that should not be null (more on should in next   the comment). "Correctness" here is a non-null property called MyItem of type Item. The page and code should be able to safely assume that the property will never be null and treat it as such.

I've been mulling this over. Nullability as a concept in the IDE is to assist in avoiding bugs and having better code. If I know that a razor page cannot and should not continue if a given property is null and as the developer will ensure that any get/post method redirects away, then the rest of the code should be able to safely assume that a property is not null. If someone changes that in the code - that's a bug and should throw an exception. If that rule changes, then it should be changed to nullable. Otherwise, your code now is full of is null checks and that seems counterproductive.

You're having these problems because you're fighting the logic of how nullability works. Since you're not initializing that property in the constructor, it can be null and should be declared as such. Whether the property should be non-null at some point in a larger program is unknown within the class. If you design the class based on that knowledge, you're creating coupling. That's how you get unmaintainable spaghetti code. This nullability issue is just the tip of the iceberg.

Since the Razor page has the knowledge of when the property "should" be non-null, the Razor page should override the nullability with ! as needed.

I'm answering myself since no one posted an answer to the question.
Before doing the below, read through the comments. There's some good info in there around the concept of nullability, testing for it, using it, etc.
In this case, there's one entry point to a Razor page and it checks for nulls and then redirects away if the property is null. The IDE does not consider this, and thus will forever warn you about a potential null error. 100s of these in a project, IMHO, reduce the efficacy of the warnings as you'll just ignore them all. To remove the warning, you just bang it at the end, which removes the warning.
MyItem = GetItems().FirstOrDefault()!;
if (MyItem == null)
{
   return Redirect("/");
}

What's good about this instead of in the property, for example, is that if someone else were to add a different entry point, they will get the warning and would have to determine the appropriate action.
I'm familiar with banging things () to address null warnings and nullability. I think I did it initially but got an error and assumed it wouldn't work...not realizing that since it was an async method I needed to wrap it in parenthesis to correctly do what I wanted...duh.
MyItem = (await GetItemAsync())!;

